# botao copiar e colar com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, formulário

Gostaria de 'criar' o comando de copiar e o comando colar com jQuery.

Tenho um formulário e preciso colocar um botão de colar nele para facilitar para o usuário

O usuário clica em copiar a URL de incorporação do youtube e no meu formulário teria um botão de "colar no input" para facilitar

Eu pesquisei mas não encontrei nada sobre isso. Encontrei botões de copiar porém de colar não.

Exemplo do que preciso:

```
$(".pasy").click(function(){

    var copy = document.execCommand('paste');
    $("#inputyou").val(copy); 

  });
```

Onde ao clicar no botão .pasy , o input recebe "false" e não o texto da área de transferência.

Comment: Essa biblioteca é bastante famosa na comunidade: https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js/

Comment: voce quer que esse botao colar simule o Ctrl + V, digitado? é isso?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581345/click-button-copy-to-clipboard-using-jquery

Comment: @andrepaulo isso mesmo, quero o botao que faça a função ctrl + v

Comment: @MurilloGoulart esta biblioteca faz a função do copiar , eu preciso também da função colar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.clipboardData.getData('Text')` vai funcionar em **alguns** browsers, mas muitos em que isso **funciona** vão abrir um `prompt` perguntando se o browser pode ter acesso ao conteúdo do `clipboard`.

A resposta é muito **provavel que não... é impossível.**

Ao invés de ter um botão pra colar, você poderia ver **como** `paste` **funciona** em diferentes tipos de **browsers**, e mostrar aos usuários que não estão familiarizados com o uso do comando obscuro de `paste` nativo **como usar** esse comando, com **instruções direcionadas ao tipo de browser** que ele está usando.

[editado]

Andei pesquisando e descobri que nao "existe" uma função global, a função copiar e livre pois o usuário esta mandando dados para a area de transferência via jquery ou javascript, bom mas a função colar, o browser "pegaria dados da área de transferencia" e com jquery o javascript, assim que o usuário carrega-se a pagina, o browser poderia pegar qualquer coisa na area de transferência, como fotos, videos, texto, dados etc.. por isso muitos navegadores bloqueiam essa atividade, no fim e melhor deixa o botao "colar" de lado para menos problemas